# Is Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK redundant when already set in manifest?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

My Activity has in manifest file:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Now if I start this activity from my code and use:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Is this redundant?

What abut this flag:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Is this redundant?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by saying redundant? Do you need to know whether "singleTask" is being overwritten or no?

Comment: By redundant I mean that is not necessary because it is already defined in manifest and it does not change anything. Like when you set a variable to the same value two times in a row. The second time is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

**1.about singleTask**

From the [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#lmodes) page of the Android dev guide:

> By default, all the activities in an
> application have an affinity  for each
> other — that is, there's a preference
> for them all to belong to the same
> task.
>
> A "singleInstance" activity stands
> alone as the only activity in its
> task. If it starts another activity,
> that activity will be launched into a
> different task regardless of its
> launch mode — as if
> FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  was in the
> intent. In all other respects, the
> "singleInstance" mode is identical to
> "singleTask".
>
> As noted above, there's never more
> than one instance of a "singleTask" or
> "singleInstance" activity, so that
> instance is expected to handle all new
> intents. A "singleInstance" activity
> is always at the top of the stack
> (since it is the only activity in the
> task), so it is always in position to
> handle the intent. However, a
> "singleTask" activity may or may not
> have other activities above it in the
> stack. If it does, it is not in
> position to handle the intent, and the
> intent is dropped. (Even though the
> intent is dropped, its arrival would
> have caused the task to come to the
> foreground, where it would remain.)

Since there is never more than one instance of the Activity with either launch mode, the back button will always take you to the existing instance of the Activity in your case.

An important difference is that "singleTask" doesn't require the creation of a new task for the new Activities being launched when something is selected. Nor will it have to remove that new task on the back button each time.

Since your Activity stack does all pertain to one user "task", and it doesn't sound like you have an intricate Intent structure where singleInstance may be beneficial to always handle them, I would suggest using the singleTask launch mode.

Here is a good blog post for more info, as well as credited for the image: [Android Activities and Tasks series – An introduction to Android’s UI component model](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activites-and-tasks-series-an-introduction-to-androids-ui-component-model/)

**2.about singleTop**

If an instance of a boot in `singleTop` mode activity already exists in the task stack stack top, then restart the Activity when a new instance is not created, but in that case reuse of the top of the stack, and will call the instance of `onNewIntent ()` method to pass a Intent object into this instance. For example, if the start mode of A `singleTop`, an example and A already exists in the top of the stack, then call the `startActivity (New Intent (this, A.class))` when A starts, A instances will not be created again, but reuse the original examples, and call the original instance of `onNewIntent (method)`. This is an example of this task stack or a A.
If a startup in `singleTop` mode activity already exists and the task stack, but not in the stack top, then its behavior and standard the same pattern, will also create multiple instances. You can look at [understand-android-activity-launchmode](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

**EDIT**

It is not redundant.

In order to record the user to open those activity, record the order of these activity open, Google introduces the task stack concept, to help maintain good user experience.

The launch mode of activity can affect the task stack .And the `Intent` flag also can affect the task stack .

You can modify the task stack pattern in the code without modifying it in the manifest file, and the flags can directly affect the task stack .

Just like `android:text="content"` in xml code .And  `tv.setText("content");` is in the java code .

Comment: I don't think you are answering my question. It is already explained in the docs what singleTop, singleInstance ... does. Can you answer my question and not talk about singleInstance?